# Method for calculating time different between two acoustic signals using analog electonics

Tags: analog, time

Think If we place two sensors at different places and record acoustic signal coming form certain direction. So, I want to find a method to calculate the time difference which two sensors detect the signal, using only ANALOG electronics.

Comment: Good luck measuring time using ANALOG electronics...

Comment: Ok, you seem to know what you want. But what is the question?

Comment: All electronics are analog at a low enough level.

Comment: I guess the two sensors are wired to some analog computer to simulate human hearing of phase differences to detect direction. but each human ear can sense direction in a hemisphere, so your suggestion must make many assumptions on a 3D angle of target and range.  but what do they sense? ? what is the emitter? It seems you must reconsider why you must restrict your options to analog only if you want to succeed.

Comment: You might look at how early radar worked, using a CRT to show the sent and returned pulses, and then using the distance between the pulses to get the distance to target. You could do that with an oscilloscope. The only problem is it requires a person to sit there and watch it.

Comment: What form do you want the result of this ANALOG calculation to take?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two separated sensors receiving the same signal, then you can use cross correlation to determine the time difference of arrival. This means placing a time delay on one signal, multiplying the two signals together and then averaging. If you vary the time delay the output of the averaging process will peak when the time delay equals the time difference of arrival. Although this process is best done using digital techniques, it can be done with analog circuitry. The hardest part is  generating the delay. For wideband signals, a tapped analog delay line can be used. For narrow band signals, a phase shifter may be adequate. This technique was used in passive ranging sonars back in the 1950's with vacuum tube circuitry, way before IC's and microprocessors.

Comment: I think you meant "1950's", not "1050's".  That's the only reasonable decade you might be thinking of.

Comment: You are quite correct. Thanks.